# 以下のエラーの対処方法について教えてください。FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/python2.7'

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

Swiftを使ってiOSのアプリを開発したく、Udemyの一番人気のSwiftコースを受講しました。２〜３年前に配信された内容ですので、同じように書き込んだプログラムが正常に動作しないことが多いですが、それも勉強と思って試行錯誤しながら、正常に動作するように頑張っているところです。

今回はpython自体に直接興味があるわけでは無いのですが、講義の内容は正常にプログラムが動作させることが目的です。今回のプログラムの内容（エラーが出るまで）を記載します。
PCはMacOS Ventura 13.1

事前に学習したCaffeモデルをXcodeプロジェクトで使用できるようにmlmodel形式に変換する まずPiPをインストールする

次にPIPを使って仮想環境をインストールする
mlmodelファイルにはCoremlToolsというAppleのパッケージが必要
動作させるためには最新のPython3ではなくPython2.7が必要
特定のディレクトリを分離して、使用するPythonのバージョンを指定

```
$ mkdir Environments
$ cd Environments
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python27
```

このとき、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/python2.7'
```

以下のブログを参考にpython2.7をインストールしました。

[【Mac OS 12.3〜】Python2のインストール][1]

しかし `/usr/bin/python3` は存在するのですが `/usr/bin/python2.7` は存在しないため、`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python27` を実行すると同様のエラーが発生してしまいます。何が悪いのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [macOS 13 Venturaではphpに続き「Python」ランタイムの同梱が終了。](https://applech2.com/archives/20221101-apple-removed-python-from-macos-13-ventura.html), [macOS VenturaでPython 3を動かす](https://diysmarthome.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/10/26/144927) あるいはそうした情報を基点に検索を続けて目的のものを探すとか？ つまり何をやりたくてその作業をやったのか、が抜けていると助言や回答を得るのが難しいと思われます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。初心者で上手く説明できるのか分かりませんが、現状について説明します。現在、UdemyのiOs&Swiftコース「Installing CoremlTools using Python PIP」で講師の指示通り進めているのですが、上手く動かないことがよくあります。今回のエラーが出る前にも私のPCがM1Macであることから、エラーが出るとの記事を読んで、.zshrcを開いて、パスを通す等の対応はしてきました。また、紹介していただいた参考記事に記載の「Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.2」をインストールをしましたが同じエラーが出ています。下手な説明で申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それらの情報はコメントではなく質問記事を編集して追記してください。それからエラーメッセージ内容は簡単で、「`/usr/bin/python2.7`というファイルまたはディレクトリが見つからない」ということなので、それがあるかどうかを確認してください。まだインストールしていないか、別の名前/場所/版数のものがインストールされているかでしょう。そして`Python 2.7`はサポート終了してから長いのでわざわざ今から使う/学ぶ必要性は低いのでは？ 何かの時のためにインストール手順程度は覚えておきたいというのなら、教材の方も最新のPC/OS環境に合わせてアップデートされている(あるいは直ぐに対応される)対処の早いサービスを選んだ方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 「demyのiOs&Swiftコース「Installing CoremlTools using Python PIP」で講師の指示通り進めているのですが、上手く動かないことがよくあります。」であれば、講座のフォーラムに質問されると講師からの回答があるかもしれません。（回答の有無やリードタイムは講師によるので何とも言えませんが）

Comment: 講師に質問シートを使って質問したことがありますが、返答がなかったためそれ以降質問したことがありません。質問の仕方が間違っていたのでしょうか？また再度やってみます。

Comment: Swiftを使ってiOSのアプリを開発したく、Udemyの一番人気のSwiftコースを受講しました。２〜３年前に配信した内容ですので、同じように書き込んだプログラムが正常に動作しないことが多いですが、それも勉強と思って試行錯誤しながら、正常に動作するように頑張っているところです。今回はpython自体に直接興味があるわけでは無いのですが、講義の内容は正常にプログラムが動作させることが目的です。今回のプログラムの内容（エラーが出るまで）を記載します。
→事前に学習したCaffeモデルをXcodeプロジェクトで使用できるようにmlmodel形式に変換する
まずPiPをインストールする
次にPIPを使って仮想環境をインストールする
mlmodelファイルにはCoremlToolsというAppleのパッケージが必要
ですが、動作させるためには最新のPython3ではなくPython２.７が必要
特定のディレクトリを分離して、使用するPythonのバージョンを指定
ところで、/usr/bin/python2.7は存在していなかったため、python2.7をインストールしてみようと考えています。

Comment: 以下のブログを参考にpython2.7をインストールしました。
https://retval.jp/blog/python2-install/
しかし、/usr/bin/python3は存在するのですが、/usr/bin/python2.7は存在しないためvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python27を実行すると同様のエラーが発生してしまいます。何が悪いのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、追加情報はコメント欄ではなく本文に直接追記してください。 / Core ML Tools は最新版 (6.1) では Python 3.6 以降のサポートで、逆に Python 2.x はサポートから外れているように見えます。 https://github.com/apple/coremltools

Comment: ルールを理解しておらず申し訳ございません。追加情報は帰宅後修正します。

Comment: おそらく参照している資料が古くて最新の情報に合っていない(資料が書かれた時点では最新だったかもしれませんが、時間が経過して最新ではなくなった時にどう対処すれば良いかの情報が無い)ために、問題の現象が発生していると思われます。資料にCore ML Toolsを含めたそれぞれのソフトウェアやライブラリのその時点での細かい版数が書いてあるなら、それに対応した古い版数のソフトウェアをインストールしてみてください。OS版数が新しくて対応していないものがあるなら、資料/教材の提供元に情報の更新を依頼してみてください。どちらも出来ないなら例えば最新の説明 [Installing Core ML Tools](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/installation) を基にPythonも2.7ではなく3.x系に読み替えて試してみてください。

Comment: 最後に書かれた`DEPRECATION`は当初の質問とは別件でしょうから、新しい質問を立てた方が良いでしょう。そしてこの質問については今までのコメントでの応答内容を質問記事に反映させて、解決した方法や手順を自己回答として投稿し、それを自己で承認しておいてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoremlToolsがpython３で動作するとの情報をいただきありがとうございます。
その後、最新のpython3.11.1をインストールし、
pip install -U coremltools
を実行したところ、インストールできました。

今回、初回の投稿で、記載の方法等、色々とご指導いただきありがとうございました。
今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。